# Python - String Splitting

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

Writing
`'1000011'.split('1')`
gives

```
['', '0000', '', '']
```

What I want is:

```
['1', '0000', '11']
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear if you want just split up a bunch of 1 and 0 characters or if there will be anything else in there besides 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex :

```
>>> re.findall(r'0+|1+','1000011')
['1', '0000', '11']
```

Answer (score 2):

The `str.split(sep)` method does not add the `sep` delimiter to the output list.

You want to *group* string characters e.g. using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In:  import itertools

In:  [''.join(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby('1000011')]
Out: ['1', '0000', '11']
```

We didn't specify the `key` argument and the default `key` function just returns the element unchanged. `g` is then the group of `key` characters.